# Store coordinates from prompt and calculate the distance

Tags: javascript, arrays, coordinates, store, prompt

I work on distance calculation between coordinates and I built something which works fine.

```
var pointsCoordinates = [[5,7],[5,8],[2,8],[2,10]];
function lineDistance(points) {
  var globalDistance = 0;
  for(var i=0; i<points.length-1; i++) {
    globalDistance += Math.sqrt(Math.pow( points[i+1][0]-points[i][0] , 2 ) + Math.pow( points[i+1][1]-points[i][1] , 2 ));
  }
  return globalDistance;
}

console.log(lineDistance(pointsCoordinates));
```

I would like to improve it a little bit and send a prompt to store coordinates sent by users.

example:

```
alert(prompt("send me random coordinates in this format [,] and I will calculate the distance))
```

I would like to store theses coordinates and calculate the distance with my function which works.

I know I have to use push but it doesn't works, someone can help me to write it? I know it's simple but... I can't do it.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var userPrompt = prompt("send me random coordinates");// e.g [100,2] [3,45] [51,6]
var pointsCoordinates = parseCoordinates(userPrompt);

function parseCoordinates(unparsedCoord) {
    var arr = unparsedCoord.split(" ");
    var pair;
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        pair = arr[i];
        arr[i] = pair.substr(1, pair.length - 2).split(",")
    }
    return arr;
}

function lineDistance(points) {
    var globalDistance = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < points.length - 1; i++) {
        globalDistance += Math.sqrt(Math.pow(points[i + 1][0] - points[i][0], 2) + Math.pow(points[i+1][1]-points[i][1], 2));
    }
    return globalDistance;
}

console.log(pointsCoordinates);
console.log(lineDistance(pointsCoordinates));
```

Comment: Not full proofed. suppose user entered a string without space then your logical will fail.

Answer (score 1):

Working and tested code. Take coordinates from the prompt and pass it to the `lineDistance` function and convert passed string into array.

```
function lineDistance(points) {
  var globalDistance = 0;
  var points = JSON.parse(points); // convert entered string to array
  for(var i=0; i<points.length-1; i++) {
    globalDistance += Math.sqrt(Math.pow( points[i+1][0]-points[i][0] , 2 ) + Math.pow( points[i+1][1]-points[i][1] , 2 ));
  }
  return globalDistance;
}

var pointsCoordinates = prompt("send me random coordinates in this format [,] and I will calculate the distance");
if (coordinates != null)
    console.log(lineDistance(coordinates)); //[[5,7],[5,8],[2,8],[2,10]]
else
    alert("Entered value is null");
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `prompt` you don't need to also wrap it with `alert`.

Also, `prompt` will return with a string value, so you'll need to **parse** the data you're getting back (unless you're fine with a string)

In this case, since you want to get back an **array of points**, parsing can be a more complicated than just converting values. My recommendation is to use `JSON.parse()` to parse the input array

In your case you could use this code

```
var coordString = prompt("send me random coordinates in this format [,] and I will calculate the distance");

try {
    var coordinates = JSON.parse(coordString);
    // now check that coordinates are an array
    if ( coordinates.constructor === Array ) {
        // this might still fail if the input array isn't made of numbers
        // in case of error it will still be caught by catch
        console.log(lineDistance(coordinates));
    }    
} catch(error) {
    // if something goes wrong you get here
    alert('An error occurred: ' + error);
}
```

I recommend reading the [MDN docs for prompt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt) if you want to know what else you can do with them.
Also, [the docs for `JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) can be useful if you want to parse values from a text string.

Comment: Yep, JSON.parse needs try-catch logic. It's a good practice, seems its a better answer

Comment: I don't know yet JSON, I'm beginner but I will study it very soon ;) thank you very much for you help it's awesome

Comment: @Moody_jr JSON is actually extremely simple, any javascript variable you have defined in your programs is already valid JSON, this means that you can store any data from a JS program as simple JSON text and load it up (or save any data) with just a simple function call. It's a very popular format for the web nowadays, and you'll understand it by just studying javascript anyway.